# CodeIgniter: Can't Display data

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am very new to CodeIgniter and I am using  v2.2.3. 
I managed to create the following code but I am unable to display the data.

Here is my **Model**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Item_Model extends CI_Model {
      function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        
    }

    // Fetch data according to per_page limit.
    public function fetch_data($id) {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get('items');
        if($query->num_rows()!==0)
        {
            return $query->result();
        }
        else
            return FALSE;
   }
}
?>
```

Here is my **Controller**

```
  function item()
  {
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
        {          
            $data["results"] = $this->item_model->fetch_data($id);       
            $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
            $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];   
            $data['title'] = '';
            $this->load->view('inventory/item_view', $data);
         }
         else
         {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Oops! You have to Login');
         //If no session, redirect to login page
            redirect('login', 'refresh');
         }
    }
```

I am unable to display data by getting the ID($id).
It says that **$id** is undefined.

I hope anyone can help

Comment: where did you define `$id` in controller?

Comment: @mehedi-pstu2k9 I actually haven't defined that. And I haven't figured out how to define it.

Comment: From where do you want to get `$id`? is is from `$_SESSION`, `$_GET` or `$_POST`?

Comment: @mehedi-pstu2k9 from $_GET, definitely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here In your controller's action add parameter you will get your data.

```
function item($id) {

    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) { 

            $data["results"] = $this->item_model->fetch_data($id);       
            $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
            $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];   
            $data['title'] = '';
            $this->load->view('inventory/item_view', $data);
         } else {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Oops! You have to Login');
         //If no session, redirect to login page
            redirect('login', 'refresh');
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to define `$id` before the model can use it. Since you said you don't know how, I'd suggest a tutorial.

http://learn-codeigniter.com/episode/codeigniter_basics

Answer (score 1):

Since you said your `$id` is from `$_GET` then try using [`$this->input->get()`](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/input.html)

```
function item()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {
        $id = $this->input->get('id', TRUE); //If $_GET param name is id
        $data["results"] = $this->item_model->fetch_data($id);
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
        $data['title'] = '';
        $this->load->view('inventory/item_view', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Oops! You have to Login');
        //If no session, redirect to login page
        redirect('login', 'refresh');
    }
}
```